# Complex rails counting query as model array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

So I have a 3 models:

```
# Rails table
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

# Rails table
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library
end

# Global table used by lots of different apps in different languages
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
  # No direct relationship because it holds many "stats" for many
  # records and not a table created using rails (.NET, Rails,
  # and Java project use same Stats table)
end
```

I have a query that looks like (to get the top 5 libraries sorted by number of checkouts):

```
# Get all books in libraries in San Antonio
# This is actually in a method because it is called by several
# Different actions.  It's placed here for reference
books = Book.joins(:libraries).where(libraries: { city_id: 4311 })

# Get number of total checkouts of books in all libraries
books.joins("INNER JOIN `stats` ON `stats`.`statsrecord_id` =
  `books`.`statsrecord_id` AND `stats`.`type` = 2").where(statsrecord_id: 
  books.map(&:statsrecord_id).uniq).group('library_id', 'library_name', 
  'address_1', 'address_2', 'city', 'state', 
  'postal_code').page(1).limit(5).order('count_all DESC').count
```

The query seems to be working great.  However, I have three questions:

First, is there a way to clean this up and still produce the same output (or is this it)?

Second, The returning records look like:

```
{[16, "Sounds Library SW", "9133 Culebra Rd", "Building 1055", "San Antonio", "TX", "78251"]=>175}
...
```

Is there a way to get this in models easily with a count?

Finally, if the returning values are listed above.  I can't seem to figure out how to pull the data from the return values?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query by writing it without using those back ticks ("`"):

```
books.joins('INNER JOIN stats ON stats.statsrecord_id = books.statsrecord_id AND stats.type = 2')
    .where(statsrecord_id: books.map(&:statsrecord_id).uniq)
    .group('library_id', 'library_name', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code')
    .page(1).limit(5).order('count_all DESC').count
```

Your returned object is just a hash and say it's name is `data_hash`. Then you can do all these things to extract the required portion (key, value etc.) of the data:

```
data_hash = {[16, "Sounds Library SW", "9133 Culebra Rd", "Building 1055", "San Antonio", "TX", "78251"]=>175}
# inspect the data_hash
puts data_hash.inspect
# get all the keys of data_hash
puts data_hash.keys.inspect
# get all the values of data_hash
puts data_hash.values.inspect
```